# IIF function in fastreport 4 not working

Tags: oracle11g, delphi-7, fastreport

I code with Delphi and use Fastreport 4 to create a report.

I have a memo38 like in picture:

[image]

In memo38, I open "code" tab and I code :

[image]

however it raises error :

> ; expected

I haven't code in Fastreport yet, so I don't know how to code it right.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Type in the Memo38 directly

```
[IIF(<frxDBDataSet1."IDPAY"> = 'NE', 'NIBUNG ESTATE', 'SARANG ESTATE')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Fast Report but I tried the following and it works...

```
begin
    memo38.Memo.Text := iif(<frxDBDataSet1."IDPAY"> = 'NE', ...)
end;
```

Or... you could select the memo38 and add event: OnBeforePrint

```
procedure memo38OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);    
begin
    TfrxMemoView(Sender).Memo.Text := iif(<frxDBDataSet1."IDPAY"> = 'NE', ...)
end;
```